# How do I initialise an empty array with static non-zero length?

Tags: vba

I've the following code:

```
Dim headerTextboxes(2) As Shape
Dim currSlide As Slide

Set currSlide = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
' Pseudocode
' Set currSlide = [null, null, null]

For i = 0 to 2
  headerTextboxes(i) = currSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(...)
Next i
```

I'm getting the error `Object variable or With block variable not set`. After some research, I believe it's because no array has actually been assigned to `headerTextboxes` yet.

The pseudocode in the comments is that I want to do. What's the correct implementation for it? All I can find online is to initialise either a zero-length array or a static length array with existing elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Set` keyword to when setting a reference to an Object.  Since `headerTextboxes` is an array of Shape Objects, every element must use `Set` to assign a reference to a Shape.

```
Dim headerTextboxes(2) As Shape
Dim currSlide As Slide

Set currSlide = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
' Pseudocode
' Set currSlide = [null, null, null]

For i = 0 To 2
    Set headerTextboxes(i) = currSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(...)
Next i
```